# Does one have to keep the printed e-visa that the immigration agent stamped upon entering Myanmar?

Tags: visas, paperwork, e-visas, myanmar

Upon entering Myanmar with an e-visa, the immigration agent stamps the printed e-visa (the e-visa that is sent by email to e-visa applicants). Does one have to keep the printed e-visa that the immigration agent stamped upon entering Myanmar? If so, for how long and can one keep a scan of it instead?

The printed e-visa with stamp  looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did they not also stamp your passport?

Comment: @MichaelHampton they did also stamp my passport